# Performance issues on Realm List

Tags: swift, set, realm, realm-list

I'm having some memory performance issues when doing operations on Realm List's. I have two objects similar to this one:

```
final class Contact: Object {
    let phones = List<Phone>()
    let emails = List<Email>()
}
```

Now I'm trying to find possible similarities between two objects of the same type (e.g. at least one element in common) that could potentially have duplicate emails or phones. In order to do so I was using `Set` operations.

```
func possibleDuplicateOf(contact: Contact) {
    return !Set(emails).isDisjoint(with: Set(contact.emails)) || !Set(phones).isDisjoint(with: Set(contact.phones))
}
```

This is a function inside the `Contact` object. I know it has a performance hit when transforming Realm List into a Set or an Array, and I'm feeling this heavily when I have a large amount of Contacts (10k or more), memory consumption jumps to more then 1GB.

So I tried replacing the above function with this one:

```
func possibleDuplicateOf(contact: Contact) {
    let emailsInCommon = emails.contains(where: contact.emails.contains)
    let phonesInCommon = phones.contains(where: contact.phones.contains)

    return emailsInCommon || phonesInCommon
}
```

This has the same performance has using the sets.

The isEqual method on the Emails and Phones is a simple string comparision:

```
extension Email {
    static func ==(lhs: Email, rhs: Email) -> Bool {
        return (lhs.email == rhs.email)
    }

    override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
        guard let object = object as? Email else { return false }

        return object == self
    }

    override var hash: Int {
        return email.hashValue
    }
}
```

`Email.swift`

```
final class Email: Object {

enum Attribute: String { case primary, secondary }

@objc dynamic var email: String = ""
@objc dynamic var label: String = ""

/* Cloud Properties */
@objc dynamic var attribute_raw: String = ""
var attribute: Attribute {
    get {
        guard let attributeEnum = Attribute(rawValue: attribute_raw) else { return .primary }
        return attributeEnum
    }
    set { attribute_raw = newValue.rawValue }
}

override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
    return ["attribute"]
}

convenience init(email: String, label: String = "email", attribute: Attribute) {
        self.init()

        self.email = email
        self.label = label
        self.attribute = attribute
    }
}
```

I'm a bit out of options in here, I've spent the entire day trying to come up with a different approach to this problem but without any luck. If anyone has a better idea, I would love to hear it out :)

Thank you

Comment: In your `Contact` object you have list of `Phones` and `Emails`. Are they realm entities too? If they are entities, they might have reverse relation to Contact object. Having this relation you may query needed information from realm without process it in memory.

Comment: @ilya yes they are Lists from realm

Comment: Could you share how these objects defined?

Comment: @ilya sure, its right there in the first code block :)

final class Contact: Object {
    let phones = List<Phone>()
    let emails = List<Email>()
}

Comment: I meant particularly definition of `Phone` and `Email` classes.

Comment: @ilya Oh, sorry, there you go :)

Comment: Do you compare every one of the 10k contacts to every other contact (so 100 million comparisons)?

Comment: @AndreasLey, No :) this a scenario where we have contacts on the server and contacts on the address book and we are comparing those from the server with the ones in the address book for possible similarities in order to merge them together. If the were 10k on the address book and 10k on the server yeah with would be a very large comparison. But on this particular case that I'm trying to solve if I remove the `Set` operations it gets very fasts and spends almost no extra memory

Answer (score 0):

Whenever something like this happens, a good start is using [Instruments](https://help.apple.com/instruments) to find out where CPU cycles and memory are consumed. Here's a good tutorial: [Using Time Profiler in Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/418/)

You omitted the code making the actual comparison, but I suspect it might be nested `for` loops or something along those lines. Realm doesn't know your use case and isn't caching appropriately for something like that.

Using Instruments, it's fairly easy to find the bottlenecks. In your case, this should work:

```
final class Contact: Object
{
    let emails = List<Email>()

    lazy var emailsForDuplicateCheck:Set<Email> = Set(emails)

    func possibleDuplicateOf(other: Contact) -> Bool {
        return !emailsForDuplicateCheck.isDisjoint(with: other.emailsForDuplicateCheck)
    }

    override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["emailsForDuplicateCheck"]
    }
}
```

And for the comparison:

```
// create an array of the contacts to be compared to cache them 
let contacts = Array(realm.objects(Contact.self))
for contact in contacts {
    for other in contacts {
        if contact.possibleDuplicateOf(other: other) {
            print("Possible duplicate found!")
        }
    }
}
```

This implementation ensures that the `Contact` objects are fetched only once and the `Set` of `Email` is only created once for each `Contact`.

Answer (score -1):

The problem you have might be solved more optimal by rebuilding a bit data structures. Getting everything in memory and trying to convert to set (building sets is expensive operation) is far from optimal :(. I suggest this solution.

Consider contact is this object (I've added `id` property). I didn't add phones objects for brevity but exactly the same approach may be used for phones.

```
class Contact: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString
    var emails = List<Email>()

    override public static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

And Email class is this one. Relation to contact is added.

```
class Email: Object {
    @objc dynamic var email: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var contact: Contact?
}
```

Having these "connected" tables in realm you may create query to find duplicated objects:

```
func hasDups(contact: Contact) -> Bool {
  let realm = try! Realm()
  let emails: [String] = contact.emails.map { $0.email }
  let sameObjects = realm.objects(Email.self)
                         .filter("email in %@ AND contact.id != %@", emails, contact.id)
  // sameObject will contain emails which has duplicates with current contact
  return !sameObjects.isEmpty
}
```

This works super fast, I've tested on 100000+ objects and executed immediately.

Hope this helps!